# Project for Java

Tags: java, variables, setter, getter

So my Java teacher wants us to write a program that simply says "Ben Barcomb is 19 years old" That's it, nothing more, nothing less.

Instead of using `System.out.println` like a normal person he wants us to use an instance variable in the Person class for the full name and age that must be `private`, he also wants a getter and setter method for the fullname and variable as well. This is the tester code I have, but I'm kind of stuck on the variable and getter/setter methods.

```
public class PersonTester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setFullname("Bilal Gonen");
    p1.setAge(76);
    String myFullname = p1.getFullname();
    int myAge = p1.getAge();
    System.out.println(myFullname + " is " + myAge + " years old.");
  }
}

public class Person{
  private String myFullname;
  private int myAge;

  public String getFullname()
    {
       return myFullname;
    }

  public int getAge()
    {
       return myAge;
    }

 public Person(String aFullname)
  {
    myFullname = aFullname;
  }

 public void setFullname()
 {
    myFullname = aFullname;
 }
}
```

---

Comment: Well, I'd recommend you to write a class named `Person` and create the methods `setFullname`, `setAge`, `getFullname` and `getAge`. Figure out what they should do by the context.

Comment: @user2291758 it seems he did that already.

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you wrote that tester yourself or if it was given to you.  The test is correct.  Are you saying you don't know how to write getters and setters? Or something else?

Comment: @RayToal I am pretty sure that is the case. OP was given the tester code and has no idea how to write the `Person` class.

Comment: Right, so I'm saying i'm not to sure how to write the variables, setters, getters, and have the context displayed. The tester was given to me in the project.

Comment: What have you tried? You're asking us to do the whole thing for you if you don't show your attempt at a Person class.

Comment: Apologies, what I had continued to fail, so I assumed it was completeley wrong.

Comment: Did the teacher give you any examples or did he expect you to search the web for how to do this?  I think you should try first based on what you know (or were given in class) _then_ google "how to write getters and setters in Java" _then_ if you are still stuck get as far as you can on your own and show your attempt before asking.  That's the S.O. way....  EDIT: feel free to update your question with the attempt!

Comment: @BenjaminBarcomb you have to wrap all your own code in an new `Class` as shown in the answers below

Comment: @Wavemaster i did, it is all under public class Person, Apologies, after the edit I realized that didn't paste in correctly.

Comment: @BenjaminBarcomb a) you are missing the `setAge(int age)` method  b) you specified a constructor for Person: `Person(String aFullname)` - you don't use this constructor in the tester. Either delete the constructor or add the name to `new Person("John Doe")`

Comment: @Wavemaster thank you, that was the whole issue, program is complete, thank you for all the assistance everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of a getter and setter. I am sure you can use this as a guide.

```
public class Person
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;    

    public void setName(String f, String l)
    {
        firstName = f;
        lastName = l;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
         return firstName;
    }
}
```

Short [**tutorial**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) on setters and getters.

Answer (score 1):

Not doing your homework for you, but I will provide some help on the getters and setters. Here's an example person class with one variable, add the others you need yourself.

```
public class Person {
    int age;

    public void setAge(int age) { // notice how the setter returns void and has an int parameter
        this.age = age; // this.age means the age we declared earlier, while age is the age from the parameter
    }

    public int getAge() { // notice the return type, int? this is because the var we're getting is an int
        return age;
    }
```

Comment: I'm asking for help, not for you to do my homework, never did I mention that. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of everyone, as well as some of the research I did myself, I got the program to compile and run correctly, here is the source code. Thanks again to everyone who assisted!

```
public class PersonTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setFullname("Ben Barcomb");
        p1.setAge(19);
        String myFullname = p1.getFullname();
        int myAge = p1.getAge();
        System.out.println(myFullname + " is " + myAge + " years old.");
    }
}
public class Person
{
   private String myFullname;
   private int myAge;

   public String getFullname()
   {
      return myFullname;
   }

   public int getAge()
   {
      return myAge;
   }

   public void setAge(int newAge)
   {
      myAge = newAge;
   }

   public void setFullname(String aFullname)
   {
      myFullname = aFullname;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The valid code is as below, use getters for the String input of `System.out.println()`

Full test code is as below;

```
public class PersonTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person();

        p1.setMyFullname("Bilal Gonen");
        p1.setMyAge(76);

        System.out.println(p1.getMyFullname() + " is " + p1.getMyAge() + " years old.");
    }
}

class Person {
    private String myFullname;
    private int myAge;

    public String getMyFullname() {
        return myFullname;
    }

    public void setMyFullname(String myFullname) {
        this.myFullname = myFullname;
    }

    public int getMyAge() {
        return myAge;
    }

    public void setMyAge(int myAge) {
        this.myAge = myAge;
    }

}
```

And the output is as below;

```
Bilal Gonen is 76 years old.
```

Note: And it will make your job easier whenever a similiar project comes, when making a POJO class (in this example the Person class), use eclipse's (or any IDE's) "generate getters/setters" shortcut (on Eclipse, you can use it with Alt+Shift+S)